# Calico network policy in Kubernetes based on Domain name Regex Matching

Tags: kubernetes, calico

I have a application running with kubernetes orchestrator. I want to implement calico network policy based on domain name Regex matching. I am seeing in [calico doc](https://docs.projectcalico.org/security/kubernetes-network-policy#create-egress-policies) that they are using ip range(CIDR) to control incoming and outgoing calls.
Can same thing be done using domain name regex matching instead of CIDR ? Some example would be helpful.

For instance I want my calico network policy to allow ingress call for domain:

```
"^.+\\.app\\.ubuntu\\.net$ ^.+\\.aws-tools.org$ ^local\\.aws-tools\\.org$"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the official Calico [documentation](https://docs.projectcalico.org/reference/node/configuration) regex matching is only used for interface selection: `interface=INTERFACE-REGEX` and `skip-interface=INTERFACE-REGEX`. Considering that regex matching for interface selection has been implemented after a feature request you can always create a feature request for domain name regex matching [here](https://github.com/projectcalico/felix/issues).

Comment: Hello @solveit. Does this [answer your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?